# Which server/webframework is better to use on an embedded device with limited resources

Tags: server, embedded

I wanted to know which server/web framework I should go for. I'm developing an application that would run on IoT-styled cameras and/or small embedded boards(like Nvidia Jetson boards). After getting the feed from the camera, I'll do some postprocessing and then I want to transfer the data directly to the browser.
Some things to consider,

- The main focus is on the local network since I'll be setting fixed local IPs for the cameras but may want to extend this in the future.
- The numbers of clients would be small, typically around the 1-10 range.
- Server will be low on ram and space
- Camera can capture 5k images and I want to be able to transfer them with minimal fps drop. Currently, the fps for 5k images is approx 10 but it may increase in future.
- The code base is in c++ so something compatible with it would be favoured.

I tried flask(even tho it is in python) and it worked great for lower resolution capture but there was a significant drop with higher resolutions.

Also, should I go with something like RTSP, RTMP or webRTC kind of thing? In an initial test with RTSP, I saw a drop in fps as well as an image quality drop.

Comment: Requests for recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SO.  Nvidia Jetson may be physically small, but in terms of resources, it cannot be described as a "small" - definitely at the higher end for embedded platforms.

Comment: I would be running another application on the Jetson that would end up taking most of the resources. Hence the restriction.

Comment: Still off-topic though.  An on-topic question you might ask would be to show the solution(s) you have tried, explain the performance and/or resource issues you found and ask how that might be resolved.  If you are willing to use a language other than your existing solution, mention that - it widens the gamut of possible solutions.  You need to be clearer also about the images - what is a "5k image"?  Is that 5k bytes, to 5K lines (HD) resolution? What is the network bandwidth.  You need to think about the tagging; perhaps IOT, video-streaming - it is not the domain of most embedded developers.